# How is the kernel module getting loaded automatically

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, yocto

I am using a Yocto based embedded Linux system. I wrote recipes for two out of tree modules. Both are part of root file system.

When the system boots, one of the module gets automatically loaded, but not the other. These are platform drivers.

I don't have any entry in /etc/modules nor in /etc/modprobe.d

How can i find out who is loading this module?

Comment: Usually it can be done by: ***a)*** hints in the module or in the configuration files for `modprobe` (as **pre** dependencies, see manual); ***b)*** module dependencies due to another module requires some symbols (see `depmod` and generated database); ***c)*** explicit load via `request_module()` API in the kernel somewhere; ***d)*** (main case) by presence and matching device that modules serves for.

Comment: Do you have any idea on module aliases helping module loading

Comment: The aliases are usually added by the `MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE()` macro.